# Need an array to store different data for different objects with the same properties (or some other strategy that makes sense)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am very new to all of this, so please forgive me if I have missed something obvious. I am building a tool that is supposed to track evaluation data for specific goals, for specific students. I have built a function using JavaScript and jQuery that does the following: 1. Initializes the array for the new student (currentStudentArray). 2. For each goal, initialize an array to hold evaluation data (newEvalArray), get the goal name, then go through each evaluation. 3. For each evaluation, it gets the date, score, and the score percentage; it packs the evaluation data into an object, then it sends the object to the array that holds the evaluation data (newEvalArray). 4. Back at the each goal level: goal name and evaluation array are packed into an object, the object is sent to the currentStudentArray. 5. Finally, the student's name and the currentStudentArray are packed into an object and that object is sent to the global array that holds the data for each student and their goals.

The problem is that my newEvalArray doesn't restart with each goal cycle, but instead it stacks all of the evaluations from the previous goal with the evaluations from the next goal and then stores all of the evaluations for both goals. What I would like it to do is only store the evaluations for that goal under that goal in the array. I haven't gotten far enough with the app to test what happens to my currentStudentsArray, but I suspect it will have the same problem once I have multiple students with different goals. But I am not working on that level yet. Right now I just want to sort out what is going on with the newEvalArray. Expected output: console should log two arrays of evaluations (one for each goal) that have a length of 4 based on the placeholders I currently have in the HTML. Instead it logs the arrays with a length of 8 and they contain all of the evaluations for every goal. Here is the code for the function:

```js
var currentStudent = "Steve";
var studentsGoalsArray = [];
var studentGoalUpdate = function () {
    var currentStudentArray = [];
    $(".goal").each(function(){
        var newEvalArray = [];
        var goalName = $(this).children("h2").text();
        console.log("Goal name is: " + goalName);
        $(".goal-eval").each(function(){
            var evalDate = $(this).children("p").text();
            console.log("EvalDate is: " + evalDate);
            var scoreContainerEl = $(this).children("div");
            var scoreContainerChildren = scoreContainerEl.children();           
            var evalScore = scoreContainerChildren[0].textContent;
            console.log("EvalScore is: " + evalScore);
            var scorePercent = scoreContainerChildren[1].textContent;
            console.log("ScorePercent is: " + scorePercent);
            console.log(evalDate, evalScore, scorePercent);
            var evalObj = {date: evalDate, score: evalScore, percent: scorePercent};
            console.log(evalObj);
            newEvalArray.push(evalObj);
            console.log(newEvalArray);
        });
    
        var goalDataObj = {goal: goalName, eval: newEvalArray}
        currentStudentArray.push(goalDataObj);
        console.log(currentStudentArray);
    });
    studUpdateArrayData = {student: currentStudent, data: currentStudentArray}
    studentsGoalsArray.push(studUpdateArrayData);
    console.log(studentsGoalsArray);
};

$("#newEvalBtn").on("click", studentGoalUpdate);
```

```html
 <div class="col" id="goals-wrapper">
            
            <!--Goals displayed here-->
            <div class="col bg-light d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap border-top-0" id="goals-container">
                
                    <div class="goal col-11 col-md-5 card my-3 bg-goal p-0">
                        <h2 class="p-2">Yes/No</h2>
                        <div class="p-3 bg-white mx-1 mb-1 overflow-auto">
                            <h3>Goal description:</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            <button class="btn bg-goal mb-3" id="newEvalBtn">New Evaluation</button>
                            <div class="list-group d-flex">
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p class="evalDate">10/15/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="score border-bottom">3/10</p> <p class="scorePercent border-bottom">30%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>11/15/20202</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">5/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">50%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>12/15/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">6/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">60%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>1/15/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">9/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">90%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goal col-11 col-md-5 card my-3 bg-goal p-0">
                        <h2 class="p-2">When</h2>
                        <div class="p-3 bg-white mx-1 mb-1 overflow-auto">
                            <h3>Goal description:</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            <button class="btn bg-goal mb-3" id="newEvalBtn">New Evaluation</button>
                            <div class="list-group d-flex">
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p class="evalDate">10/25/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="score border-bottom">5/10</p> <p class="scorePercent border-bottom">50%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>11/25/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">7/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">70%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>12/25/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">8/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">80%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>01/25/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">10/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">100%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 
                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant html as well, and even better make it a working snippet. Also if you can post an actual output you get from your code and one that is how you would want it to be.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I think I have done what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `newEvalArray` resets fine, but you fill it with all goal evaluations.

This happens because you use `$(".goal-eval").each` which finds all `.goal-eval` nodes in the page, not just those under the current `.goal`.

You need to add the correct context to limit the search. Since that line is inside the `$(".goal").each` handler, you can just pass `this` as the second paremeter.

So using `(".goal-eval", this).each` should fix your problem.

```js
var currentStudent = "Steve";
var studentsGoalsArray = [];
var studentGoalUpdate = function () {
    var currentStudentArray = [];
    $(".goal").each(function(){
        var newEvalArray = [];
        var goalName = $(this).children("h2").text();
        $(".goal-eval", this).each(function(){
            var evalDate = $(this).children("p").text();
            var scoreContainerEl = $(this).children("div");
            var scoreContainerChildren = scoreContainerEl.children();           
            var evalScore = scoreContainerChildren[0].textContent;
            var scorePercent = scoreContainerChildren[1].textContent;
            var evalObj = {date: evalDate, score: evalScore, percent: scorePercent};
            newEvalArray.push(evalObj);
        });
    
        var goalDataObj = {goal: goalName, eval: newEvalArray}
        currentStudentArray.push(goalDataObj);
    });
    studUpdateArrayData = {student: currentStudent, data: currentStudentArray}
    studentsGoalsArray.push(studUpdateArrayData);
    console.log(studentsGoalsArray);
};

$("#newEvalBtn").on("click", studentGoalUpdate);
```

```html
<div class="col" id="goals-wrapper">
            
            <!--Goals displayed here-->
            <div class="col bg-light d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap border-top-0" id="goals-container">
                
                    <div class="goal col-11 col-md-5 card my-3 bg-goal p-0">
                        <h2 class="p-2">Yes/No</h2>
                        <div class="p-3 bg-white mx-1 mb-1 overflow-auto">
                            <h3>Goal description:</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            <button class="btn bg-goal mb-3" id="newEvalBtn">New Evaluation</button>
                            <div class="list-group d-flex">
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p class="evalDate">10/15/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="score border-bottom">3/10</p> <p class="scorePercent border-bottom">30%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>11/15/20202</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">5/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">50%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>12/15/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">6/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">60%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>1/15/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">9/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">90%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="goal col-11 col-md-5 card my-3 bg-goal p-0">
                        <h2 class="p-2">When</h2>
                        <div class="p-3 bg-white mx-1 mb-1 overflow-auto">
                            <h3>Goal description:</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            <button class="btn bg-goal mb-3" id="newEvalBtn">New Evaluation</button>
                            <div class="list-group d-flex">
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p class="evalDate">10/25/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="score border-bottom">5/10</p> <p class="scorePercent border-bottom">50%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>11/25/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">7/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">70%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>12/25/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">8/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">80%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="goal-eval list-group-item bg-goal">
                                    <p>01/25/2020</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="border-bottom">10/10</p> <p class="border-bottom">100%</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 
                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```